# Page Redirection Issue using session Id

Tags: asp.net

I have login page I am doing authentication using http handler  to precompiled application.

Already in the application sessions are used to redirect to a page after authentication.

Please suggest me how can i redirect using session variable through http handlers in precompiled application.

Note:i have no idea which session variable used.

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant is that you can't access session like `Session["key"]` then you can try the following

```
HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

string myValue = session["key"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the values stored in [HttpContext.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)

e.g.

In your HttpHandler's ProcessRequest method

public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
 string url = context.Session["Url"];
}